How to debug "Invalid tag name" error with "npm install"
I have an older CRA project that I'm having trouble using npm install or npm update with, e.g.:
$ npm update
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name ">=^16.0.0" of package "react@>=^16.0.0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/abcd/.npm/_logs/123456.log

I get the same Invalid tag name error if I run npm install --legacy-peer-deps.
None of the dependencies entries in package.json have tags formatted in the way described in the error message, including the react dependency.
I am using npm v10.1.0.
I have 33 packages listed as dependencies in this project's package.json file.
One problem is that the debug log file that npm writes did not include information on which package in package.json is having this installation problem.
To try to drill down to this issue, I manually reinstalled each of the 33 package dependencies serially with the --legacy-peer-deps option, e.g.:
$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps react@^16.8.6
...
$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps react-bootstrap-table-next@^4.0.3
...

Etc. Once I have done this, I still run into the same Invalid tag name error if I run npm install. However, if I run npm install --legacy-peer-deps, there is no error.
My question would be:
How do I find out which specific package(s) I need to update, so that I can just run npm install on the overall project, without getting the Invalid tag name error, and without needing to add legacy peer dependencies?
Installing each package manually, in serial, did not uncover any Invalid tag name error, but I had to use the --legacy-peer-deps option when installing them.
When I do not use the --legacy-peer-deps option, attempting to install the 33 packages on their own resulted in the Invalid tag name error.
I'm trying to avoid a blanket update to whatever is most current version of every one of the 33 package dependencies, especially because of API changes between major versions. For instance, going from React 16 to 18 (while ideal, I'm sure) will almost certainly break the project and force a major rewrite.
Unless the problem is caused by something else entirely, I'm trying to understand how to get more information out of npm to troubleshoot which specific package dependency is problematic and update just that.

You can delete node_modules, and comment half of your dependencies, then run npm  i. If your error disappears, you have eliminated 50% of the dependencies, that could've caused the error. Rince and repeat until you find the culprit :D.
You can also search all files with VSC / any file search inside node_modules to contain >=^16.0.0, the package that has this as a peer or smth similar will show up.
